# Can a polynomial be almost always divisible by a member of a finite set of primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Special case of [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture)

Let $f(x)$ be non-constant irreducible polynomial with integer
coefficients, no fixed prime factor and positive
leading coefficient. Let $S$
be a finite set of primes.

> Q1 Is it possible $f(n)$ to be divisible by a member of
>   $S$ for almost all natural $n$?
>
> Q2 Must $f(n)$ take at least one prime value for
>   natural $n$?

Comment: Q2 is essentially the k=1 case of Schinzel's Hypothesis H, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel's_hypothesis_H , and is open for any non-trivial polynomial of degree two or more (even for $f(x) = x^2+c$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to Q1 is "no". The value of $f(n)$ mod $p$ depends only on the value of $n$, mod $p$.

Let $N$ be the product of the primes in $S$. Assuming "almost all" means "all but finitely many", then that means that for $n$ sufficiently large, the set $n+1,\ldots,n+N$ are all multiples of primes from $S$. But since all this is invariant modulo $N$, that means every number is a multiple of some prime from $S$.

The question is then, can we cover $1,\ldots,N$ by residue classes mod primes from $S$ without using all the residue classes modulo any prime (because if we did we have a fixed prime factor)? And the answer is "no", by an easy application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem: choose a residue class modulo each $p\in S$ which is not used; they give a unique residue mod $N$ which is uncovered.

Comment: I like to think about this in different terms: if $f(n)$ is divisible by some prime in $S$ for all but finitely many $n$ then there is a single prime (in $S$) that divides $f(n)$ for every $n$.

Comment: Thank you, I see. I believe your result is sharp (it is possible to not cover only a single residue class mod the product).

Answer (score 1):

I guess my answer is morally the same as James Cranch's one, but Q1 is false even in degree $1$: let $f(x)=ax+b$ and $\{p_1,\dots,p_s\}=S$. Then by assumption $f$ is not the constant polynomial $0$ modulo any $p_i$ and we let $\alpha_i$ be an integer which is a non-root $\mod{p_i}$. The Chinese Remainder Theorem says that the finite set of equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x\equiv \alpha_1 \pmod{p_1}\\
\vdots\\
x\equiv \alpha_s\pmod{p_s}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
has infinitely many solutions.